# Caliburn.Micro Add Click event to Image for ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro to make Wpf Control. Part of my XAML code is as below:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Devices" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="border" 
                            BorderBrush="Black" 
                            BorderThickness="0" 
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            Margin="20">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageMain}" Height="200" />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       Margin="0 0 0 20"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="border" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

And it works properly. Now what I want is to add a Click event to my Image and pass the Devices.deviceId to the event.

I tried different ways but they don't work.  Can anybody give me a hint?  Thanks a lot.

I tried this:

```
...
<Button>
   <Image Source="{Binding ImageMain}" Height="200" />
</Button>
```

but it won't show the image.

Comment: You don't just want to use the selection capabilities of a ListBox? Or just put the Image in a Button?

Comment: What is the `Devices.deviceId`? Can you share your view model? Actuall, `cal:Message.Attach` can help you

Comment: It is one common property of the Devices class. It is not in my view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$dataContext` to pass the required information as paramter. For example,

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageMain}" Height="200"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown]=[Action ImageClicked($dataContext)]" />
```

Where ImageClicked is defined in ViewModel as

```
 public void ImageClicked(Device data)
 {

 }
```

You can now retrive the deviceid information from `data` instance and do the required processing. You could read more on Caliburn Micro actions [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

Comment: Thanks very much, Anu. I tried but getting some error: Additional information: No target found for method ImageClicked.

Comment: Hope you have the method in your view model? One with matching signature

Answer (score 0):

With Anu's help. Finally done. Here is the complete code. Hope it will help someone else in the future:

The View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConfigUI.Views.ShowDevicesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConfigUI.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" 
                   Text="{DynamicResource ShowDevice}"
                   Margin="0 0 0 20"
                   />

        <ItemsControl x:Name="Devices" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="border" 
                            BorderBrush="Black" 
                            BorderThickness="0" 
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            Margin="20">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageMain}" Height="200" 
                                    cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown]=[Action ImageClicked($dataContext)]" 
                                   />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 20" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="border" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The ViewModel:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using ConfigUI.Library.Models;
using ConfigUI.Local;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConfigUI.ViewModels
{
    public class ShowDevicesViewModel: Screen
    {
        private BindableCollection<DetecctedDevice> _devices;

        public BindableCollection<DetecctedDevice> Devices
        {
            get { return _devices; }
            set {
                _devices = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Devices);
            }
        }

        public ShowDevicesViewModel()
        {
            _devices = new BindableCollection<DetecctedDevice>(LocalDevices.GetLocalDevices());
        }

        public void ImageClicked(DetecctedDevice selectedDevice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the contents of ImageMain?? I'm trying a very basic code to change image based on the button clicked. But doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @Machindows Sorry I didn't keep the code. but the ImageMain was just a file path to the image.